# How to calculate the last digits of a big number using modular arithemtic?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to calculate the last 2 digits of $9^{9^{9^{9}}}$ using modular arithmetic somehow. Please help.

Comment: See patterns in the last two digits of powers of $9$. They will repeat after some time. To do this, you need not take powers of $9$, but instead take the last two digits each time. For example, $9^2 = 81$, $9^3 = 729$, $29 \times 9 = 261$, etc. While doing this, you will see that  this pattern recurs. Find the period of recurrence and the answer is $9^{9^9}$ modulo the period.

Answer (score 3):

I start with the long way that works every time.  Skip to the last paragraph for a very short solution in this case.

---

Your goal is to compute
$$
9^{9^{9^9}}\pmod{100}.
$$

One way to compute this is to use Euler's totient function $\varphi$.  Since the totient function is multiplicative, $$
\varphi(100)=\varphi(2^2)\varphi(5^2)=(2^2-2^1)(5^2-5^1)=2\cdot 20=40.
$$

Euler's theorem states that
$$
a^{\varphi(100)}\equiv 1\pmod{100}
$$
for $a$ relatively prime to $100$.  Therefore, it is enough to compute
$$
9^{9^{9^9}\pmod{\varphi(100)}}\pmod{100}.
$$

Therefore, our problem is reduced to
$$
9^{9^9}\pmod{40}.
$$
By following the same pattern, we see that 
$$
\varphi(40)=\varphi(2^3)\varphi(5)=(2^3-2^2)(5^1-5^0)=4\cdot 4=16.
$$
Therefore, we need to compute 
$$
9^{9^9\pmod{\varphi(40)}}\pmod{40}.
$$
Therefore, our problem reduces to computing
$$
9^9\pmod{16}.
$$
Following in our pattern, it is enough to compute 
$$
9^{9\pmod{\varphi(16)}}.
$$
Since $\varphi(16)=2^4-2^3=8$, we know that
$$
9^9\equiv 9^1=9\pmod{16}.
$$
Therefore, 
$$
9^{9^9}\equiv 9^9\pmod{40}.
$$
Moreover, since $9^9=9\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot 9$, and $9\cdot 9=81\equiv 1\pmod {40}$, $9^9\equiv 9\pmod{40}$.

Putting this together, 
$$
9^{9^{9^9}}\equiv 9^9\pmod{100}.
$$
Now, this is fairly straight-forward to compute since
$$
9^9=(9^3)^3.
$$
Since $9^3=729\equiv 29\pmod{100}$, we have that
$$
9^{9^{9^9}}\equiv 9^9\equiv (29)^3\pmod{100}.
$$
Since
$$
29^3=24389\equiv 89\pmod{100},
$$
we have that
$$
9^{9^{9^9}}\equiv 9^9\equiv (29)^3\equiv 89\pmod{100}.
$$
Therefore, the last two digits are $89$.

---

It is faster, however, to notice that $9^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$, so we only need to compute $9^{9^9}\pmod{10}$ because multiples of $10$ in the exponent correspond to multiplying by $1\pmod{100}$.  Therefore, all we need is the remainder modulo $10$ in the exponent, i.e.,
$$
9^{9^{9^9}}\equiv 9^{9^{9^9}\pmod{10}}\pmod{100}.
$$
Since $9\equiv -1\pmod{10}$, and $9^9$ is odd, we know that $9^{9^9}\equiv -1\equiv 9\pmod{10}$.  Therefore, the original expression is equivaent to $9^9\pmod{100}$, which can be calculated as above (or on a calculator).

Comment: Is there a way to go about this without using Euler's totient function?

Comment: I added a version without the totient function at the end (last paragraph).

Comment: can you elaborate on that faster version? I'm struggling to follow your line of logic

Comment: Since multiples of $10$ in the exponent give you factors of $1$, which don't matter, you only need to know the ones digit of the exponent, which is $9$.